# outer boxedminipage environment cancelling inner environment

Tags: environments, minipage, polyglossia

I am using boxedminipage2e to create a framed box with some text in it.  I am also using polyglossia, since sometimes this text is in Arabic, sometimes in English.

The language environment within these framed boxes is behaving strangely.
In the MWE below, I have wrapped the contents of the custom environment `textbox` in `begin{english}...end{english}` and also tried to wrap individual paragraphs manually in the code.  This switch to english works for the first paragraph only; and if a new paragraph begins, it begins in a RTL direction, as if it had changed back to Arabic.  See the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Wue.jpg).

It seems I have to wrap every single paragraph in `begin{english}...end{english}` and this is crazy.
Main question: how can I wrap such english text more easily?

As a bonus question, the MWE has some lines commented out; these lines work outside of the new `textbox` environment, but fail to compile as written in the MWE.  I think the reason is the same as the problem above, but I'm not sure.  Is there a way I can get them to work *inside* the new `textbox` environment?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, inner=1.6in, outer=1in, includefoot] {geometry}
\usepackage{boxedminipage2e}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.90]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand{\restarabic}{\let\@arabic\orig@arabic}
% \makeatother
\NewEnviron{textbox}[1]
{
\nopagebreak
\begin{boxedminipage}[t][#1][t]{\linewidth}
\begin{english}
    \BODY
\end{english}
\end{boxedminipage}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{textbox}{3in}
This is some initial text.

This is a second paragraph

\begin{english}
This is  a third paragraph.

This is a fourth paragraph
\end{english}
% \restartarabic
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{enumerate}

This is a fifth paragraph
\end{textbox}

\begin{english}
This is outside the box
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro for arabic numbring is `\restarabic` not `\restartarabic`.

Just place your `textbox` environment Inside `english` environment  not the opposite, to write arabic text Inside `textbox` you can use `Arabic` envitonment like this

```
\begin{Arabic}
نص عربي 
\end{Arabic}
```

**Your code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, inner=1.6in, outer=1in, includefoot] {geometry}
\usepackage{boxedminipage2e}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.90]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restarabic}{\let\@arabic\orig@arabic}
\makeatother
\NewEnviron{textbox}[1]
{
\nopagebreak
\begin{boxedminipage}[t][#1][t]{\linewidth}
\begin{english}
    \BODY
\end{english}
\end{boxedminipage}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{english}
\begin{textbox}{3in}
This is some initial text.

This is a second paragraph

This is  a third paragraph.

This is a fourth paragraph

\restarabic
\begin{enumerate}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{enumerate}

This is a fifth paragraph
\end{textbox}
\end{english}

\begin{english}
This is outside the box
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, but I don't understand why.  Can you point me to some rules which explain (1) why my code didn't work and (2) why changing the hierarchy of environments makes a difference?